# BitmapFactory 's decodeByteArray and decodeStream returns null

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to decode ARGB `byte` array into `Bitmap` to display it as an `ImageView`.
I tried using `BitmapFactory`'s `decodeByteArray()` and `decodeStream()` but both way gives null as `Bitmap`.

But when I create bitmap using `createBitmap()` and `setPixels()` it works perfect. Here is the working code.

*data* is the byte array of size   `imageWidth*imageHeight*4`

```
int[] pixels=new int[imageWidth*imageHeight]; 
int i=0,j=0;
while (i<imageWidth*imageHeight*4) {         
    pixels[j]= bytesToInt(data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2],data[i+3]);
    i += 4;
    j++;
}
Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap. createBitmap( imageWidth,imageHeight,Bitmap.Config .ARGB_8888)        
bmpf.setPixels(pixels, 0, imageWidth , 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
   //---------------------- definition of bytesToInt()
int bytesToInt(byte b1,byte b2,byte b3,byte b4)
{
    return (((b1& 0xff)<<24)+((b2 & 0xff)<<16)+((b3&0xff)<<8)+(b4&0xff));
}
```

But I need to achieve this using `decodeByteArray()` or `decodeStream()` because for the later way I need to create integer array for `setPixels()` from the `byte` array , which  is inefficient. 
What i am trying to implement is a video player , there fore it need to display around 15 frames/images per second.

Hopes some one can help me in this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Peter Knego.  But for me the video rendering code is complete and working , problem is with slowness in rendering video frames images because of this setPixels function.


         int i=0,j=0;
     while (i<imageWidth*imageHeight*4) {

    pixels[j]= bytesToInt(data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2],data[i+3]);
    i += 4;
    j++;
     } 


This code take around 50ms for execution. So I want to replace my code which current uses this createBitmap() and setPixel() using  BitmapFactory's decodeByteArray() ordecodeStream()

Comment: and yes,byte[] is of ARGB format which is given as input to BitmapFactory.decodeStream

Answer (score 0):

Video plater plays video streams, i.e. a stream of video frames. `Bitmap.decodeStream` expects a stream of image bytes, i.e. a stream of bytes in JPEG or PNG format.

Is your stream of bytes in correct format, i.e. jpeg or png?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Peter Knego. But for me the video rendering code is complete and working , problem is with slowness in rendering video frames images because of this setPixels function. int i=0,j=0; while (i<imageWidth*imageHeight*4) { pixels[j]= bytesToInt(data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2],data[i+3]); i += 4; j++; } This code take around 50ms for execution. So I want to replace my code which current uses this createBitmap() and setPixel() using BitmapFactory's decodeByteArray() ordecodeStream()

Comment: and yes,byte[] is of ARGB format which is given as input to BitmapFactory.decodeStream